# useNavigate not working in useEffect catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, try-catch

I used a try and catch block inside  useEffect, when there is an error, the code inside the catch block (the console logs) runs except that which re-routes the user to another page using useNavigate(). This question has been asked before but I found no suitable answer.

```
   export const useFetchUser = (url) => {
    const [commentsList, setCommentsList] = useState("");
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState("");
  const Navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchDAta() {
      try {
        const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        });
        if (response) {
          const chatArray = await response.json();
          setCommentsList(chatArray.allComments);
          setUserInfo(chatArray.user);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("re-route"); // this works
        Navigate("/errorPage"); // this doesnt
      }
    }
    fetchDAta();
  }, [url, Navigate]);
    return { commentsList, userInfo, setCommentsList, setUserInfo };
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.